# List similar search results in combobox as the user types in query

Tags: c#, combobox

At the moment, my address lookup application only returns one result after the user types in their query and clicks on the search button e.g. search for **Mow Mead** returns the first match in the list.

[image]

However, I'd like for it to fill the **AddressEntry** combobox with all the addresses that match **Mow Mead**, as opposed to only one search result, as seen below. How can I go about doing this in C#? My assumption is that it would take place on a keypress event, but I'm not too sure on how to fill the combobox programmatically with the live results.

I've included a sample of my csv [here](http://pastebin.com/BRKBPxnX).

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String addressText = GetAddress(AddressEntry.Text);
        AddressEntry.Text = addressText;
    }

    private String GetAddress(String addressText)
    {
        var strLength = File.ReadAllLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");
        var strLines = File.ReadAllLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");

        foreach (var line in strLines)
        {
            var fields = line.Split(',');

            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                string needle = addressText.Trim().ToLower();
                string haystack = field.Trim().ToLower();
                if (haystack.Contains(needle))
                    return line.Trim();
            }
        }

        return "Nothing found.";
    }

    private void AddressEntryField_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something here, i.e. fill the combobox with the nearest matches as 
        // the user types in their entry and then they can select their final 
        // decision from the combobox.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file to get your addresses to search through, like you're currently doing:

```
var addresses = File.ReadAllLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");
```

If your search box has only one search term, like "Mow Mead", you can return matching results like this:

```
var matches = addresses.Where(address =>
    address.Contains(AddressEntry.Text.Trim().ToLower());
```

If your search box could have multiple comma-delimited terms, you could split them first:

```
var searchTerms = AddressEntry.Text.Split(',');
```

And then search your addresses for any of those search terms:

```
var matches = addresses.Where(address => searchTerms.Any(address.Contains));
```

Finally, just assign the collection of strings (addresses) to your ComboBox:

```
yourComboBox.DataSource = matches;
```

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks for the response. At which stage does it programmatically fill the combobox with the results? I was expecting a search term like Mow Mead to return all of the entries containing Mow Mead in the drop down (as seen here http://pastebin.com/BRKBPxnX, there are quite a few). Right now, my code just fetches the topmost result.